# Post a JSON object to an MVC controller and retrieve an IEnumerable type

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to retrieve a JSON from my AJAX, which is in the form of

```
{ID_USER : ID_INSTRUCTION}
```

My JSON result :

```
[{"658":"81"},{"658":"82"},{"658":"90"},{"658":"101"}]
```

This my code jQuery for post AJAX:

```
$("#boutton-add").on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newFormData = [];
    var usr = $('.usr_id').attr('id');
    jQuery('.tab_inst tr[name="inst"]').each(function (i) {
        var tb = jQuery(this);
        var obj = {};
        tb.find('button[name="delete"]').each(function () {
                obj[usr] = this.id;
        });
        if (obj[usr] != null)
            newFormData.push(obj);
    });
    var jsonresult = JSON.stringify(newFormData); // object return instruction of user after removing and adding informations 

    //alert(jsonresult);

    //----------------------ajax to posting json to actionresult

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Usr_Inst/set_user_inst/',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: jsonresult,
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(jsonresult);
        }
    });
});
```

now all things gone right.

Now I want to make adding or removing programs from my USER_INSTRUCTION table that has two columns ID_USER and ID_INSTRUCTION, to do this I need an ActionResult method that has a parameter `IEnumerable <USER_INSTRUCTION>`.

```
public ActionResult set_user_inst(IEnumerable<USER_INSTRUCTION> jsonresult)
{
    // adding or removing programs.
}
```

My Model class is like :

```
[Table("DPH.USER_INSTRUCTION")]

public partial class USER_INSTRUCTION
{
    [Key]
    public decimal ID_USER { get; set; }
    public decimal ID_INSTRUCTION { get; set; }

    public virtual INSTRUCTION INSTRUCTION { get; set; }
    public virtual USERS USER { get; set; } }
```

Values that I got from MVC controller in parameter when the project is running is `ID_USER = 0 an ID INSTRUCTION = 0`

Comment: You should post the relevant code to the question! Not the link to some image!.

Comment: Don't put screen shots here, Put the code

Comment: It's worth noting that [requests for urgency do not go down well here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - please read `:-)`.

Comment: For `Some HELP Please !!!!` even after I made a note about requesting urgency, I have downvoted. We do not respond well to demands here.

Comment: Ok thanks for you're remarks !

Answer (score 1):

You post the following key-value pairs to server, but you try to bind it to `IEnumerable<string>`.

```
[{ "658": "81" }, { "658": "82" }, { "658": "90" }]
```

According to the method parameter `IEnumerable<string>`, you want to save data into an array at client-side like this  `["81" ,"82" , "90" ]`, and post it server.

**- Or -**

You post the following JSON, and bind it to strongly-typed model at server.

### Json

```
[{ "Number": "81" }, { "Number": "82" }, { "Number": "90" }]
```

### Model

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

### Action Method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetUserInst(IEnumerable<UserModel> collection)
{
    // C# Method name should start with Capital.
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I already answered you question - posted data and Action Method's parameter must match. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I think is the same i have editing my post 
the name of the data in ajax is "jsonresult" the same this of method's parameter ?!!

Comment: Before posting a whole bunch of properties, you want to start with a single property such as Number in my answer. Then work your way up.

Comment: I want to get for each key-value , a USER_INSTRUCTION object who have an Id_user and id_ instruction and their type is decimal. 

So i want to have an IEnumerable<USER_INSTRUCTION> from my json result.

So for each key-value that i have in my JSON is an USER_INSTRUCTION object